# How do I stop emails 'pushing' to Apple Mail (macOS Sierra)

Tags: macos, mail.app

I don't want Mail to automatically download new mail. I want to manually do this by choosing Mailbox > Get All New Mail.

I have tried setting the preference 'Check for new messages: Manually' in Preferences > General, thinking this would solve the issue. But email still pushes to my iCloud account!

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour so new mail only delivers when I ask the app to fetch it?

Thanks!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

According to this topic:
[Disable the Push IMAP (IDLE) email in macOS Sierra](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7690558?start=0&tstart=0), Apple has removed that option.

Comment: What I ended up doing was setting up an iCloud Mail rule to mark all incoming messages as 'read' – its not as good, but at least my Mail app is no longer littered with distracting 'unread' symbols.

Comment: Ridiculous choice by Apple. Users are being progressively trained in how to engage with their devices, by gradually removing their ability to choose...